# Decoding MultiType Array and Unknown Length Array within JSON using Swift

Tags: json, swift

I've seen questions like this asked before on Stack Overflow, however none match this complexity. When I attempt to apply the same principles I've seen in similar StackOverflow questions, I get stuck. I'm new to using JSONs in Swift, and certainly understand how to decode fairly complex JSONs. However, this is just beyond my reach.

```
{
  "def": [
    {
      "sseq": [
        [
          [
            "pseq",
            [
              [
                "sense",
                {
                  "sn": "1 a (1)",
                  "dt": [
                    [
                      "text",
                      "{bc}an extremely young child"
                    ]
                  ],
                  "sdsense": {
                    "sd": "especially",
                    "dt": [
                      [
                        "text",
                        "{bc}{sx|infant||}"
                      ]
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              [
                "sense",
                {
                  "sn": "(2)",
                  "dt": [
                    [
                      "text",
                      "{bc}an extremely young animal"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          ],
          [
            "sense",
            {
              "sn": "b",
              "dt": [
                [
                  "text",
                  "{bc}the youngest of a group "
                ],
                [
                  "vis",
                  [
                    {
                      "t": "He is the {wi}baby{/wi} of the family."
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            "sense",
            {
              "sn": "2 a",
              "dt": [
                [
                  "text",
                  "{bc}one that is like a baby (as in behavior) "
                ],
                [
                  "vis",
                  [
                    {
                      "t": "When it comes to getting shots, I'm a real {wi}baby{/wi}."
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ],
          [
            "sense",
            {
              "sn": "b",
              "dt": [
                [
                  "text",
                  "{bc}something that is one's special responsibility, achievement, or interest "
                ],
                [
                  "vis",
                  [
                    {
                      "t": "The project was his {wi}baby{/wi}."
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            "sen",
            {
              "sn": "3",
              "sls": [
                "slang"
              ]
            }
          ],
          [
            "sense",
            {
              "sn": "a",
              "dt": [
                [
                  "text",
                  "{bc}{sx|girl||}, {sx|woman||} "
                ],
                [
                  "uns",
                  [
                    [
                      [
                        "text",
                        "often used in address"
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ],
          [
            "sense",
            {
              "sn": "b",
              "dt": [
                [
                  "text",
                  "{bc}{sx|boy||}, {sx|man||} "
                ],
                [
                  "uns",
                  [
                    [
                      [
                        "text",
                        "often used in address "
                      ],
                      [
                        "vis",
                        [
                          {
                            "t": "Hey {wi}baby{/wi}, nice car!"
                          }
                        ]
                      ]
                    ]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ],
        [
          [
            "sense",
            {
              "sn": "4",
              "dt": [
                [
                  "text",
                  "{bc}{sx|person||}, {sx|thing||} "
                ],
                [
                  "vis",
                  [
                    {
                      "t": "is one tough {wi}baby{/wi}"
                    }
                  ]
                ]
              ]
            }
          ]
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

To clarify, I only want the object that contains the "sn" and "dt" properties and looks like the following:

```
{
   "sn":"b",
   "dt":[
          [
              "text",
              "{bc}the youngest of a group "
          ],
          [
                     "vis",
               [
                    {
                         "t":"He is the {wi}baby{\/wi} of the family."
                    }
               ]
          ]
     ]
}
```

What makes this so complicated is that:

- The first "sseq" (for example) contains a 5D array that combines strings with more arrays within the same array, which happens at multiple levels.
- Sometimes, it is unknown how many arrays I have to decode to get to that level.

Any help on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The below function will generate an array with all values that has any of the given keys

```
func extract(_ keys: [String], from value: Any, to result: inout [String, Any)]) {
    if let dictionary = value as? [String: Any] {
        var anyFound = false
        for key in keys {
            if let value = dictionary[key] {
                result.append((key, value))
                anyFound = true
            }
        }

        if !anyFound {
            for item in dictionary {
                extract(keys, from: item.value, to: &result)
            }
        }
    } else if let array = value as? [Any] {
        for item in array {
            extract(keys, from: item, to: &result)
        }
    }
}
```

and you can use it like this

```
var array = [(String:Any)]()
do {
    if let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any] {
        extract(["dt", "sn"], from: result, to: &array)
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Then it is only a matter of decoding/converting the content of the array.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness-sake, another approach to make this work is to encapsulate the types of values that a JSON could hold as an enum with associated values:

```
enum Json {
    case obj([String: Json])
    case arr([Json])
    case str(String)
    case int(Int)
    case num(Decimal)
    case bool(Bool)
    case null
}
```

Then you could make it `Decodable` by trying to decode either as a dictionary, failing that - as an array, and finally, failing that, as a primitive value:

```
extension Json: Decodable {
    // Need this to decode arbitrary keys
    struct DynamicKeys: CodingKey {
        var stringValue: String
        var intValue: Int? = nil
        init?(stringValue: String) { self.stringValue = stringValue }
        init?(intValue: Int) { return nil }
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        
        // try to decode as a dictionary
        if let container = try? decoder.container(keyedBy: DynamicKeys.self) {
            var dict: [String: Json] = [:]
            for key in container.allKeys {
                let jsonValue = try container.decode(Json.self, forKey: key)
                dict[key.stringValue] = jsonValue
            }
            self = .obj(dict)

        // try to decode as an array
        } else if var container = try? decoder.unkeyedContainer() {
            var array: [Json] = []
            while !container.isAtEnd {
                let jsonValue = try container.decode(Json.self)
                array.append(jsonValue)
            }
            self = .arr(array)

        // try to decode a primitive
        } else if let container = try? decoder.singleValueContainer() {
            if let int = try? container.decode(Int.self) {
                self = .int(int)
            } else if let decimal = try? container.decode(Decimal.self) {
                self = .num(decimal)
            } else if let str = try? container.decode(String.self) {
                self = .str(str)
            } else if let bool = try? container.decode(Bool.self) {
                self = .bool(bool)
            } else if container.decodeNil() {
                self = .null
            } else {
                fatalError("this shouldn't have happened")
            }
        } else {
            fatalError("this shouldn't have happened")
        }
    }
}
```

You could provide some convenience subscripts to access an array or a dictionary:

```
extension Json {
    subscript(index: Int) -> Json? {
        if case .array(let array) { return array[index] } 
        else { return nil }
    }

    subscript(index: String) -> Json? {
        if case .obj(let dict) { return dict[index] } 
        else { return nil }
    }
}
```

Then you could decode it normally, and you'd get an enum of possibly more enums as a result:

```
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Json.self, jsonData)

let innerJson = json["foo"]?[0]?["bar"]
```